# Try to prove Buckingham's $\pi$ theorem in a simple way

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics, dimensional-analysis

Can I prove Buckingham's $\pi$ theorem like this?

This is the version of the theorem I need to prove:
Consider a model with variables $x_1,...,x_n$, with $k$ fundamental dimensions involved, then $n-k$ dimensionless products of $x_1,...,x_n$ can be defined.

My attempt to prove:

Let $L_1,...,L_k$ are the fundamental dimensions, assume we can use them as a basis of the units of variables (the units are understood as vectors).

Say the unit of each $x_i$ is $L_1^{m_{i,1}}...L_k^{m_{i,k}}$, express the unit as vector $(m_{i,1},...,m_{i,k})$. We can check they have vector space structure.

Then finding $(r_1,...,r_n)$ such that $x_1^{r_1}...x_1^{r_n}$ is dimensionless is the same as solving the equation

$$r_1(m_{1,1},...,m_{1,k})+...+r_n(m_{n,1},...,m_{n,k})=(0,...,0)$$

Re-express:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
m_{1,1} & ... & m_{n,1}\\ 
\vdots  &  & \vdots \\ 
 m_{1,k}& ... &  m_{n,k}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
r_1\\ 
\vdots \\ 
r_n
\end{bmatrix}=\textbf{0}$$

Then the problem becomes finding the dimension of the kernel of the $k \times  n$ matrix. Since there are $k$ fundamental dimensions involved, the matrix has full rank, so the result follows from the rank-nullity theorem.

This mostly follow from wikipedia's proof, but there was logarithm and some abstract algebra theorems, and I try to find a simpler proof.

Comment: Title: Where can we find the $\pi$ here?

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's the name of theorem, where pi has nothing to do with the famous constant.

Comment: Wikipedia calls it [Buckingham π theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_π_theorem), so indeed $\pi$ and not "pi". The parameters are named $\pi_1,\ldots ,\pi_p$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see, I will change the title, thanks. Btw, do you think my proof is correct? Please let me know if there are any mistakes in the proof.